# How can I measure CPU and Memory in java web application run through tomcat in netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, netbeans, cpu-usage

How can I measure CPU and Memory in java web application run through tomcat in netbeans.

I just need something like CPU utilized is 4% and memory utilization is 40 MB.

something like process explorer in windows, where i can chose firefox for example and i can see how much percentage is used and memory?

Appreciate your support.

P.S.: I used Netbeans Profiler and it was very detailed that i could not understand what exactly amount of memory or CPU is utilized!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in the Projects Window, right click on your Web project and select "Profile"

A Profile window appears.  On the left top corner of the window, click on the drop down arrow and select the "Telemetry" screen.

Click on the Profile button again and select to start the application on the web server of choice.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: when i right click on project and chose profile i got the following screen:https://ibb.co/gKZWmF

Comment: I saw a screen like your screenshot when I used NetBeans 7.x.  I am using NetBeans 8.2.  The profiling windows in my NetBeans look as on http://wiki.netbeans.org/ProfilerFirstSession

Answer (score 0):

What OS do you run on ? All of them have somewhat advanced monitors that might help you.

Directly though java though, netbeans profiler seems like the way to go. Which stats do you want specificaly ?

Comment: The profiler is giving me time used not the percentage of CPU and gives it very detailed for each class, for memory it shows heep size and heep used which one is consumed from the OS itself, i could not understand it, one more thing i need to collect both of them at the same time if possible

Comment: well, it only gives me data about Netbeans:(